# Linux/Bash - Remove text between every 2 occurrences of " ^[[ " characters

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a file which contains the following contents (along with the line numbers):

```
      1 Started by user ^[[8mha:AAAAmx+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQTGjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc83PyU1x6OyILUoJzMv2y+/JJUBAhiZGBgqihhk0NSjKDWzXb3RdlLBUSYGJk8GtpzUvPSSDB8G5tKinBIGIZ+sxLJ        E/ZzEvHT94JKizLx0a6BxUmjGOUNodHsLgAzeEgZ+/dLi1CL9jMSi4ozMvMxsAJ8wnzvEAAAA^[[Blahblah
      2 [abc] - Loading variables.
      3 Building on master 
      4 [test] 
      5 Started job
      6 Build log at - /xyz/file
      7 Ended job
      8 Started by user ^[[8mha:AAAAmx+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQTGjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc83PyU1x6OyILUoJzMv2y+/JJUBAhiZGBgqihhk0NSjKDWzXb3RdlLBUSYGJk8GtpzUvPSSDB8G5tKinBIGIZ+sxLJ        E/ZzEvHT94JKizLx0a6BxUmjGOUNodHsLgAzeEgZ+/dLi1CL9jMSi4ozMvMxsAJ8wnzvEAAAA^[[computer
      9 Started job
```

I would like to remove all the text between every 2 occurrences of the characters `^[[` (including the characters) such that my new file looks like this:

```
      1 Started by user Blahblah
      2 [abc] - Loading variables.
      3 Building on master 
      4 [test] 
      5 Started job
      6 Build log at - /xyz/file
      7 Ended job
      8 Started by user computer
      9 Started job
```

How could I do this in Bash?

Comment: What have you tried?  For the most part this should be fairly trivial.

Comment: Just use sed.  The invocation is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there's only ever two on the line, you can just use:

```
sed 's/\^\[\[.*\^\[\[//'
```

as per the following transcript:

```
pax> echo '1 Started by user ^[[REMOVE-ME^[[Blahblah
...> 2 [abc] - Loading variables.
...> 3 Building on master
...> 4 [test]
...> 5 Started job
...> 6 Build log at - /xyz/file
...> 7 Ended job
...> 8 Started by user ^[[REMOVE-ME-AS-WELL^[[computer
...> 9 Started job' | sed 's/\^\[\[.*\^\[\[//'

1 Started by user Blahblah
2 [abc] - Loading variables.
3 Building on master 
4 [test] 
5 Started job
6 Build log at - /xyz/file
7 Ended job
8 Started by user computer
9 Started job
```

The `sed` command simply replaces everything between the first and last `^[[` sequence with nothing, with the `\` characters there to simply escape the characters that would otherwise be special to the `sed` regular expression engine.

One thing to watch out for there, that will work if the delimiters is exactly as you describe. I only mention this because `^[` is sometimes the representation of the `ESC` character. If that *is* the case, you'll need to adjust the regex to suit:

```
sed 's/\x1b\[.*\x1b\[//'
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
sed 's/\(\^\[\[\).*\1//' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.